# What is the regex to match a newline character?

Tags: regular-expressions

In Emacs regex, `\n` doesn't match a new line character `\n`.

1. Am I correct that `$` matches the position between a new line
   character and the character right before the new line character.
   e.g. for a string `abc\n`, `$` matches the position between `c` and
   `\n`?
2. What is the regex that matches `\n`?

Comment: Could you provide a minimum working example?  Maybe I'm missing something, but `(re-search-forward "\n")` works fine for me.

Comment: Your file might use \r\n for new lines and it may be that you need to include \r in your regexp, so `abc\r\n` instead of `abc\n`.

Comment: @Dan: C-M-s and M-x occur both match `\n` to `n`. my buffer is in Fundamental mode. This happens to any text, so any text with new line or letter `n` is a working example

Comment: @Jordon: C-M-s and M-x occur both match `\r\n` to `rn`

Comment: @Tim, yes because if you are entering them interactively you'd need to do a quoted inserts, C-q C-m, and C-q C-j respectively. You could enter \r\n if you were entering them into a lisp string.

Comment: @Dan The string you used, "\n", consists of a single newline character, which certainly matches the newline character! If you wanted to prove that the two character sequence `\n` matches a newline, you'd need to escape the backslash in the string, i.e., to use `(re-search-forward "\\n")`. If you do that you'll see that `\n` matches the letter `n`.

Comment: @Jordon: `(looking-at "\r?\n")` matches both line styles.

Answer (score 35):

1. Yes. `$` matches the *end of the line*, not the *newline character* which comes after the end of the line.
2. Do `C-M-s C-q C-j`. `C-q` is the default binding for `quoted-insert` and works in the minibuffer too. This expression literally searches for a newline: `C-j`.

Comment: 2. are you saying the new line character can not be represented as an escape sequence in Emacs regex?

Comment: Whether searching for a newline interactively or via elisp (e.g. `(looking-at "^J")` where *^J* is inserted by `C-q C-j`), the `C-q C-j` approach always works. But when using elisp functions like the same `looking-at` `\n` works too; `M-: (looking-at "\n") RET` will eval to true if the cursor is at the end of the line (and there's a newline after that).

Comment: Just to mention, if using `regexp-builder`, you're able to recognize a new line with `[\n]`.

Comment: @Nsukami_: C-M-s and M-x occur both match `[\n]` to `n`.

Answer (score 20):

As Dan comments, the regex that matches a newline *is* a newline.

You can represent a newline in a quoted string in elisp as `"\n"`. There is no special additional *regexp-specific* syntax for this -- you just use a newline, exactly like any other literal character.

If you are entering a regexp *interactively* then you can insert the newline with <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd>, as kaushalmodi's answer points out.

Comment: Thanks! In emacs (not in elisp), is C-q C-j the only way to match a new line character? `\n` doesn't match a new line character.

Comment: Yes. Well, more specifically, *typing a newline* is the only way to match a newline character when entering a regexp interactively (as there is no regexp escape sequence for a newline), and `C-q C-j` is the most reliable way to type a newline at a prompt.

Comment: There can be workarounds, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20056634/3873799

Comment: @alelom I don't understand what you're trying to say there.  That Q&A appears to be about EOL conventions (which vary and may or may not involve carriage return characters), but this question is about matching a newline character.