# How to non-interactively use regular expressions over more than one line?

Tags: regular-expressions

Consider a buffer as below. As explained in the documentation `.` matches any character but newline. Also `\n` matches newline. So evaluating `(re-search-forward "a\(.\|\n\)*b" nil t)` should normally have a match in this document. But it does not.

(As explained in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9549/ when using regular expressions interactively, `a\(.\| C-q C-j \)` seems to be fine in this situation).

```
a
b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape your regexp string properly:

```el
(re-search-forward "a\\(.\\|\n\\)*b" nil t)
```

When I place cursor at the beginning of buffer with given contents and
evaluate expression (via `eval-expression`) I get answer `4`. That's a
match.