# Search and replace two consecutive newlines

Tags: search, replace, newlines

Running spacemacs 0.200.

I am sorry if it is too basic. But I am just not able to get this.

How do I convert two consecutive newlines with some text, say, 'there were two newlines here'?

I could see the notation for special character classes like `[[:alnum:]]`, etc. But no clue about newlines.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Do you want to replace all  occurrences of `<br><br>` with some text?

Comment: @StarBug No. I want to replace two consecutive newlines with the text '<br><br>'. Anyway, I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Interactively, you can use `replace-regexp` for this. Just type `C-q C-j` to indicate a newline in the REGEXP.

Comment: @StarBug: Please post that comment as an answer.

Comment: Related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9548

Answer (score 3):

Interactively, you can use `replace-regexp` for this. Type `C-q C-j` to insert a newline character in the minibuffer (so you would need to type this twice).

In Elisp strings you can use `\n` to indicate a newline, so you would write
`(re-search-forward "\n\n")`
to search for two consecutive newlines. You can then use a `replace-match` command for the replacement.

Comment: The same should work with `query-replace` instead of `replace-regexp`.

Comment: Why doesn't `C-q RET` work?